# Getting user information (email specificlyy) before he verified his email

Tags: facebook, email, verification

Hi,

I am trying to get the user email address, and in a specific scenario I have a problem.
The scenario is:
1.       Register a new facebook user
2.       Do not verify email on FB
3.       Try to do FB connect from the app
4.       On the pop up(FB pop up) that say you have to verify the email(on FB), click on the "allow" button.(DO NOT CLOSE THE POP UP)
5.       Verify the email with FB
6.       Click "allow" once more on the pop up - the pop up will close
-----a.       The app will be allowed on the user FB account but when we will try to get his basic information his email will be show as FB email
7.       To get his real email we need to remove the app from the user FB account and then try again from the app so that the app will get new permissions to the user account.

Is there a way to not be must to remove the app from the user account and re-allow it?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an extreme edge case my QA people would find and report as a bug. :D  When a user is connecting to an application, they can specify the email (either their real one, or a facebook proxy one). So it appears that when a user has not verified their email, but allows access to the app, they are not given a dropdown to choose which email to use (real vs proxy) because facebook does not have a verified "real" one on file.  So, even with that asside, there is no way for a user to "change" which of the two emails to use for an app without deauthorizing and then reauthorizing the app.